# Entity Framework Core: a one to many relationship model, but in each iteration, only the last inserted is entity is accessible

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web project in which I use MVC pattern and Entity Framework Core. I have two models (generated via Entity Framework DBFirst approach).

First model is the company model and the other one is plant model. Each company can have many plants. In my view I want to post new plants to my plant table and display all plants of the company which  I posted plants to. The plants I enter are successfully posted to DB, no problem there, however In my controller the behavior is unintended. When a new plant is posted, the company has only the last posted plant on its plants field. It is supposed to have all of the plants.

It behaves as if in each posting action the plant that existed before is destroyed and the new one is added. Since models are generated by EF Core, I believe I'm doing something wrong in my controller. What is a better way to achieve the task I described?

The sections of code I believe that are relevant:

Model for Company:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Data.Models;

public partial class Company
{
    public short CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string? CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Plant> Plants { get; } = new List<Plant>();
}
```

Model for Plant:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Data.Models;

public partial class Plant
{
    public short PlantNo { get; set; }

    public short CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string? PlantName { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company{ get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Relevant controller code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Data.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using UI.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace UI.Controllers;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly ProjectContext  _context;
    private Company _companyDeclared;
    private List<Plant> _holdPlants;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ProjectContext context, List<Plant> holdPlants, Company companyDeclared)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
        _holdPlants = holdPlants;
        _companyDeclared = companyDeclared;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    // FILL THE OTHER FIELDS OF Company
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CompanyDetail(Company company)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            short companyId = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<short>(TempData["CompanyId"].ToString());
            TempData.Keep("CompanyId");

            var companyToUpdate = _context.Companys.Find(companyId);
            companyToUpdate.CompanyName = company.CompanyName;
           
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("PlantsDetail");
        }

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult PlantsDetail()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // CREATE A NEW PLANT WITH THE INITIAL CompanyId 
    // ALL PLANT'S CREATED BELONG TO THE SAME COMPANY
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PlantsDetail(Plant plants)
    {
        short companyId = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<short>(TempData["CompanyId"].ToString());
        TempData.Keep("CompanyId");
        //short companyId = 117;
        _companyDeclared = _context.Companys.Find(companyId);
        //company.Plants = new List<Plant>();

        if (_companyDeclared == null)
        {
            _companyDeclared = new Company { CompanyId = companyId };
        }

        var plantToAdd = new Plant { CompanyId = companyId, Company = _companyDeclared, PlantNo = plants.PlantNo, PlantName = plants.PlantName};

        _companyDeclared.Plants.Add(plantToAdd);
        
        _holdPlants.AddRange(_companyDeclared.Plants.ToList());
        
        // UNUSED TRY CATCH BLOCK, VIEWBAG DOESN'T BEHAVE PROPERLY
        try
        {
            ViewBag.myCompany = _companyDeclared;
            ViewBag.plantsList = _holdPlants;
        }
        catch (Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException ex)
        {
        }

        _context.Plants.Add(plantToAdd);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
}
```

The section in my view where I list all plants:

```
@if (ViewBag.myCompany!= null)
{
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.plantsList)
    {
        <th>@item.PlantNo</th>
        <td>@item.PlantName</td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">UPDATE</button></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button></td>
    }
}
```

Comment: ervin answered this then removed his answer but your issue is going to be this: `_companyDeclared = _context.Companys.Find(companyId);` This will load the company but will not load any Plants for that company that the DbContext isn't already tracking. Use `_companyDeclared = _context.Companys.Include(x => x.Plants).Single(x => x.CompanyId == companyId);` This will ensure any existing plants are loaded with the company.

Comment: That makes sense, I thought by adding the company all subfields would be automatically included, but that would be computationally expensive in a more complex project I guess. Thanks a lot, this solved my problem.